# Ugly Shadows On Model?

Tags: modeling, lighting

I was trying to create a low poly model and the shadows on her hair look pretty bad. They look fine on the rest of the body. I'm sure it's a modeling error on my end, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is an image:[image]

Here is the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iVsAB1jhIeeZM4LSjsm5mwWmVu2pLkuQ/view?usp=sharing

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more geometry to have a smooth surface.

If you add a subsurf modifier the problem goes away.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Select the Sun and change it to a Hemi in the Lamp settings. That will give you better shadows.

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail how that helps? Hemi lamp type is not really supported in Cycles.

Comment: This didn't work, someone sent me a link about terminator artifacts though. Basically their is no solution for low poly models in cycle atm.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58927)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Regardless of whether it is correct or accurate this answer does attempt to answer the question.

Comment: It does, I marked as not an answer to convert to a comment, mostly because it is short and doesn't provide much context or explanation, not for it's accuracy. Technically it might even work even if unexpectedly